# How to attach library source to JetBrains Rider

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

How can I attach the library source, such as `MySql.Data.dll` (source code file:mysql-connector-net-6.9.9-src.zip), to the IDE?

When I <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> the library class, it  decompiles the dll file automatically, but I want to attach the source code to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Rider will always either decompile sources or download sources from a symbol server.